When Genju of the Fens dies, does the swamp go in the graveyard?
When I play Genju of the Fens, I enchant a swamp, and I pay the mana to transform the swamp to a 2/2 black spirit creature, but it’s still a land and it dies because of blocking or spells. Then the enchantment goes in the graveyard, because the creature died, but I thought, because of the spell that the swamp is still a land and a land can’t die.

Genju of the Fens has an ability that triggers "When enchanted Swamp is put into a graveyard". It wouldn't have that ability unless that was something that could happen.


a land can’t die

This is wrong. Once you activate Genju's ability, the permanent is simultaneously both a creature and a land and can be destroyed just as any other creature can. While it's difficult to prove that there's no special exception for creature-lands, I'd argue this would likely be in Comprehensive Rule (CR) 305 "Lands" or CR 704.5g:

704.5g If a creature has toughness greater than 0, it has damage marked on it, and the total damage marked on it is greater than or equal to its toughness, that creature has been dealt lethal damage and is destroyed.

This is a relatively common play pattern with Liquimetal Coating and Karn, the Great Creator - you first use Liquimetal Coating to make the an opponent's land an artifact, and then use Karn's +1 ability to make the artifact an artifact creature; it is then put into it's owner's graveyard (via CR 704.5f) for being a creature with zero toughness.
(Rules references to the 2024-04-10 Comprehensive Rules)
